# Why is there a "c" prefix in the C++ version of C libs?

Tags: c++, c

`math.h`  -> `cmath`

`stdlib.h` -> `cstdlib`

I understand the difference between the ".h" version and the "c-prefix" version, but what was the reason to choose to use the "c" prefix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT**: Okay, we have some people who maybe didn't read the question carefully enough, or made assumptions on what the question meant or how answers were to be interpreted.

I'm answering the below question here:

> but what was the reason to choose to use the "c" prefix?

---

To emphasize that it's originally from the C language, I presume.

Comment: @Platinum Azure Do you have any sources to confirm it?

Comment: The ".h" version also has its origins in the C language, for me that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I haven't found any sources, but I think @FredOverflow is spot on. As for clashes in filenames, that's quite significant because a C++ compiler looks for files in certain places with certain suffixes, and it would suck if the wrong file ended up being included because of a name collision. As for the `.h` version, that's just because the designers decided to use the `.h` suffix to indicate it's a header. It's more a convention than anything, though.

Comment: @Fábio: I think they just wanted to be consistent with the naming convention for C++ library headers, i.e., no extension.

Comment: @Platinum Azure But even without the "c" prefix the files would have different extensions. (C versions with a "h" extension and C++ versions without extensions)

Comment: @Fábio Diniz: C/C++ compilers are notorious for implementing the language constructs in different and sometimes incompatible ways. I don't think there's anything in the standard that says, "if the users says `#include <stdio>`, the compiler may not look for stdio.h instead".

Comment: You're right, I took a look at the standard and there's nothing about it.

Comment: @Platinum Azure:  In the first place, 16.2 says that the implementation will look for headers in an implementation-defined manner.  Given `#include <stdio>`, there's nothing that says the implementation can't look for `/usr/include/stdio.h` or other places.  In the second place, the "as-if" rule means that the compiler doesn't actually have to read a standard header file, as the effects can be more or less hard-coded in.

Comment: @David Thornley: Agreed. I just didn't have a copy of the standard from which to read :-)

Comment: @Platinum: my apologies, I read the question wrongly and didn't think the true subject needed such a long discussion.

Comment: @rubenvb: No worries. Sorry for overreacting a bit.

Comment: @Platinum: no, you're in your right to ask for a reason, I was wrong not to give one myself.

Comment: @Fábio "The ".h" version also has its origins in the C language, for me that doesn't make much sense" -- What doesn't make much sense? "h" stands for header. "c" stands for C. Those aren't parallel, but there's no reason to expect them to be.

Answer (score 13):

The name qualification is required to disambiguate between std-namespace-qualified versions of the C library headers and same-named C++ library headers.  For example:  "string.h" contains original C string functions, "cstring" contains std-qualified C string functions, and "string" contains C++ string classes.  Without the name qualification, the latter two names would clash.

Comment: @rubenvb He explained the reason to use a prefix, i asked why they choose the "c" prefix. Only Platinum Azure tried to answer my question.

Comment: @Fábio: except that his answer is at the least incomplete as it misses the whole point.

Comment: @Fábio: @Jollymorphic: I am confused today, sorry for that. I thought your comment was on a different answer.

Comment: @Fábio If that's **all** you wanted to know, it's a bit of a "duh". Platinum Azure even said "I presume" -- in other words, PA offered the answer that **seems** obvious, without even knowing if its the right answer. Of course, we all know that it is the right answer if we have any sense.

Comment: @Jim Well, i thought there was a reason that everyone but me knew, but it seems that no one knows the answer for sure.

Comment: @Fábio There is a reason that everyone knows: "c" stands for "C". Beyond that, no one knows anything "for sure".

Answer (score 5):

The headers that end with .h are the original C headers. The ones with the c prefix (and no extension) are the C headers versions incorporated by the C++ Standard (the prefix "reminds" you that). In theory, everything inside them should be inside the **std** namespace.

Comment: I know the difference, thanks! But why the use of a "c" prefix to indicate the versions incorporated by the C++ Standard?

Comment: @Fábio - I guess it's just a way of telling you... Hey you are programming in C++, but this is a header originally from C. Still, it's **now** conformant with C++ and everything is inside namespace **std**.